# Mysql recursive query to get parent category

Tags: mysql, left-join, recursive-query

I have 3 tables:

1. users
2. user_groups
3. groups

A user can be in multiple (sub)groups. They are stored in the `user_groups` table like this

```
+--------------+--------------+---------------+
| id           | user_id      | group_id      | 
+--------------+--------------+---------------+
| 1            | 1            | 23            |
+--------------+--------------+---------------+
| 2            | 2            | 24            |
-----------------------------------------------
```

Now in my `groups` table, the top categories are `parent_id = 0`

```
+--------------+--------------+---------------+
| id           | parent_id    | name          | 
+--------------+--------------+---------------+
| 1            | 2            | Group 1.1     |
+--------------+--------------+---------------+
| 2            | 0            | Group 1       |
+--------------+--------------+---------------+
| 3            | 2            | Group 1.2     | 
+--------------+--------------+---------------+
| 4            | 3            | Group 1.2.1   |
+--------------+--------------+---------------+
| 5            | 2            | Group 1.3     |
+--------------+--------------+---------------+
```

Now I want to build a query which gives me all the parent groups for all users. I did some research about recursive queries and I found this particular post: 
[How to create a MySQL hierarchical recursive query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20215744/how-to-create-a-mysql-hierarchical-recursive-query)

But I have no idea how I should approach this when I join the tables.

This is what I got so far:

```
SELECT
    `users`.`id`,
    `users`.`first_name`,
    `users`.`last_name`,
    `users`.`email`,
    `users`.`language`,
    `groups`.`name`,
    `groups`.`parent_id`
FROM `users`
    LEFT JOIN `user_groups`
        ON `user_groups`.`user_id` = `users`.`id`
    LEFT JOIN `groups`
        ON `groups`.`id` = `user_groups`.`group_id`
WHERE
    `users`.`created` 
    BETWEEN
        DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 365 DAY) AND NOW()
```

But this query just gets me the name and the id of the subgroup. What I want is the top level group.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I don't think you can do this in general with a single query. Do you happen to know in advance how many levels can be in your hierarchy?

Comment: No, the levels are unlimited.. My final solution would be do to this with php, but I think it would be a nice exercise to get this working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The typical solution is to create a stored function that returns the top-level group for any given group by tracing the parentage up until it finds a row with parent_id = 0.

Then you can apply that function to each group that the user is a member of, and select the distinct set of top level groups.

Something like this should work for you:

```
delimiter $$

drop function if exists get_top_level_group_id $$

create function get_top_level_group_id (p_group_id int) returns int
begin 
  declare v_return_val int;
  declare v_group_id int;
  declare v_parent_id int;
  declare continue handler for not found
    begin
      return -1;
    end;

  set v_group_id = p_group_id;
  set v_parent_id = p_group_id;

  while v_parent_id != 0 
  do 
    set v_group_id = v_parent_id;

    select `parent_id` 
    into v_parent_id 
    from `groups` 
    where id = v_group_id;
  end while;
  return v_group_id;
end $$

delimiter ;
```

Then you can update your query like this to get those users and their distinct top-level groups:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    `users`.`id`,
    `users`.`first_name`,
    `users`.`last_name`,
    `users`.`email`,
    `users`.`language`,
    get_top_level_group_id(`user_groups`.`group_id`) as top_level_group_id
FROM `users`
    LEFT JOIN `user_groups`
        ON `user_groups`.`user_id` = `users`.`id`
WHERE
    `users`.`created` 
    BETWEEN
        DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 365 DAY) AND NOW()
```

Comment: Thanks, I will certainly check this later today! I got my report using php, but I will test this. Thanks!